# is there a trick how to access server variables in lighttpd logfile?

Tags: lighttpd

I have installed GeoIP on my server next to lighttpd.
I would like to log the country in my lighttpd access log.
Is there a way to include server variables?

Answer (score 0):

`"%{GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME}e"` but this is only available if the HTTP request is to a dynamic backend (CGI, FastCGI, SCGI, etc) since the GeoIP lookup, while fast, is not free, and so is not performed unless a CGI environment is prepared for the dynamic backend (or if a small snippet of custom lua code is used with lighttpd mod_magnet).

Unless you need the GeoIP information for use in processing the request (e.g. by a dynamic backend), it is recommended that you simply log the IP address in your access log and then use geoip to resolve the IPs to country name when you process your logs offline (and not on the critical path to serving the HTTP request).